# How to generically replace every undefined value within a tree like object structure with the null value?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, data-structures, typechecking

is there a better way to check of empty data in JSON data ?

Here is the type of JSON I have, sometimes data is missing, which is normal :

```
{
  "sumRatings": "Private info",
  "phoneNum": "Private info",
  "firstname": "Private info",
  "email": "Private info",
  "fullname": "Private info",
  "talentType": "Private info",
  "ratingCount": "Private info",
  "creationTime": "Private info",
  "lastname": "Private info",
  "currentPosition": "Private info",
  "rgpd": "Private info",
  "bio": "Private info",
  "company": "Private info",
  "whatsapp": "Private info",
  "emptyComs": "Private info",
  "id": "Private info"
}
```

Here is how I did it :

```
for (const item of allDocs) {
  var generalData = {
    bio: item.bio == undefined ? null : item.bio,
    fullname: item.fullname == undefined ? null : item.fullname,
    company: item.company == undefined ? null : item.company,
    position: item.position == undefined ? null : item.position,
    profilImg: item.profilImg == undefined ? null : item.profilImg,
    talentType: item.talentType == undefined ? null : item.talentType,
    rating: item.rating == undefined ? null : item.rating,
    contacts: {
      gmeets: item.gmeets == undefined ? null : item.gmeets,
      zoom: item.zoom == undefined ? null : item.zoom,
      phone: item.phone == undefined ? null : item.phone,
    },
    skills: item.skills == undefined ? null : item.skills,
    email: item.email == undefined ? null : item.email,
    firstname: item.firstname == undefined ? null : item.firstname,
    lastname: item.lastname == undefined ? null : item.lastname,
    phone: item.phoneNum == undefined ? null : item.phoneNum,
    ratingCount:
      item.ratingCount == undefined ? null : item.ratingCount,
    sumRatings: item.sumRatings == undefined ? null : item.sumRatings,
    currentPosition:
      item.currentPosition == undefined ? null : item.currentPosition,
    creationTime:
      item.creationTime == undefined ? null : item.creationTime,
    rgpd: item.rgpd == undefined ? null : item.rgpd,
    emptyComs: item.emptyComs == undefined ? null : item.emptyComs,
  };
  console.log(generalData);
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to avoid puting `... == undefined ? null : ...` on every line.
Maybe a function that would take the item atributes, check if they are undefined and return "null" if undefined or the actual value if not undefined.

Comment: Why are you preferring `null` here? Also what JSON?

Comment: So you trying to map undefined to null, you can search of how to map object keys...

Comment: You appear to have a JavaScript Object not JSON

Comment: `"Private info,` <<< is invalid JSON

Comment: Why do this in the first place? Are you trying to add all properties that don't exist yet or something? What is the end goal here?

Comment: There's no need to. If you're OK for `myObject.unknown` being nullish (`undefined`) by default.

Comment: Also, just for reference, you can use Object.keys() to get an array of the property names of an object. You don't even need that here though, you just need an array of all keys, then use `item[key]` to dynamically reference all of them. This is essentially a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: First, if any of the object's properties features an `undefined` value then this object was never retrieved from [valid JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#javascript_and_json_differences) data since the `undefined` value is not part of JSON conform encoding. Second, checking all (nested) entries of a tree like structure usually is done by a recursive approach. Third, [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns all of an objects own enumerable key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above comment ...

> *"First, if any of the object's properties features an `undefined` value then this object was never retrieved from [valid JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#javascript_and_json_differences) data since the `undefined` value is not part of JSON conform encoding. Second, checking all (nested) entries of a tree like structure usually is done by a recursive approach. Third, [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns all of an objects own enumerable key-value pairs."*

```js
function recursivelyNullifyUndefinedValues(obj) {
  Object
    .entries(obj)
    .forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (!!value && (typeof value === 'object')) {

        recursivelyNullifyUndefinedValues(value);

      } else if (value === undefined) {

        obj[key] = null;
      }
    });
  return obj;
}

const sampleData = {
  talentType: "foo",
  rating: "bar",
  contacts: {
    gmeets: undefined,
    zoom: undefined,
    phone: "baz",
  },
};
console.log('before ...', { sampleData });

console.log('after ...', { returnValue: recursivelyNullifyUndefinedValues(sampleData) });
console.log('after ...', { sampleData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

Since the OP seems to create a somehow more structured data item from kind of a flat/plain data config there are other techniques/tools like [Destructuring assignment / Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring), [Destructuring assignment / Default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_values_2) and [Destructuring assignment / Rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_in_object_destructuring)

```js
function recursivelyNullifyUndefinedValues(obj) {
  Object
    .entries(obj)
    .forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (!!value && (typeof value === 'object')) {

        recursivelyNullifyUndefinedValues(value);

      } else if (value === undefined) {

        obj[key] = null;
      }
    });
  return obj;
}

function createNullifiedStructuredDataFromFlatConfig(config) {
  const {
    // handle nullification already
    // via destructuring default values.
    gmeets = null, zoom = null, phone = null, ...rest
  } = config;

  // take care of whatever was left with the `...rest` data.
  return recursivelyNullifyUndefinedValues({
    contacts: {
      gmeets,
      zoom,
      phone,
    },
    ...rest,
  });
}

const flatItemData = {
  talentType: 'foo',
  rating: 'bar',
  gmeets: undefined,
  zoom: undefined,
  phone: 'baz',
  skills: undefined,
  email: 'buzz',
}
const structuredSampleData =
  createNullifiedStructuredDataFromFlatConfig(flatItemData);

console.log({ flatItemData, structuredSampleData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what would be most useful is a function that takes an output object specification describing where its elements are to be found in the original structure.  It's simple enough to write recursively.  This version allows you to specify a property of the input for any location in the output, passing `null` for those that are missing:

```js
const restructure = (spec) => (o) =>
  Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (spec) .map (([k, v]) => [
    k,
    Object (v) === v ? restructure (v) (o) : v in o ? o [v] : null
  ]))


const spec = {
   bio: 'bio',  
   fullname: 'fullname',
   company: 'company',
   position: 'position',
   profilImg: 'item',
   talentType: 'talentType',
   rating: 'rating',
   contacts: {
     gmeets: 'gmeet',
     zoom: 'zoom',
     phone: 'phone',
   },
   skills: 'skills',
   email: 'email',
   firstname: 'firstname',
   lastname: 'lastname',
   phone: 'phoneNum',
   ratingCount: 'ratingCount',
   sumRatings: 'sumRatings',
   currentPosition: 'currentPosition',
   creationTime: 'creationTime',
   rgpd: 'rgpd',
   emptyComs: 'emptyComs',
}


const o = {sumRatings: "Private info", phoneNum: "Private info", firstname: "Private info", email: "Private info", fullname: "Private info", talentType: "Private info", ratingCount: "Private info", creationTime: "Private info", lastname: "Private info", currentPosition: "Private info", rgpd: "Private info", bio: "Private info", company: "Private info", whatsapp: "Private info", emptyComs: "Private info", id: "Private info"}

console .log (restructure (spec) (o))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

And if we want to restructure an array of such items, it would be just

```js
const newItems = items .map (restructure (spec))
```

There are two useful extensions we might want to consider:

- This probably doesn't handle arrays well.  We could extend it to do so.
- We might really want to reformat data from a nested object, not just a flat one.  So it might be nice to have entries such as `bio: 'additionalInfo.personal.biography'`, or for the most flexibility, `bio: ['additionalInfo', 'personal', 'biography']` so that `bio` gets the value of the `biography` property of the value at the `personal` property of the value at the `additionalInfo` property in our input object, defaulting again to `null`.

Neither of these would be difficult.  We can leave them as exercises for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the `x == undefined ? null : x` parts to `x ?? null` and wrap it in a function, but you might want to look into a schema validation library like [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup).

Answer (score -2):

You can also shorthand the check simply with boolean or. For example.

```
...
var generalData = {
    bio: item.bio || null,
    fullname: item.fullname || null,
    company: item.company || null,
    ...
```

Expression`(x || null)` evaluates to null if x is undefined or null. Otherwise it evaluates to x.

Comment: True, but OP is primarily asking how to avoid hard-coding each property.